# Angular Mat Calendar Disable date based on Rest result

Tags: angular, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I am using Angular material calendar (i.e) mat-calendar. I am trying to disable some of the dates in the calendar based on dynamics value.

**HTML**

```
    <mat-calendar [headerComponent]="exampleHeader" [dateFilter]="filterDates"></mat-calendar>
```

I am using a custom header, to catch next/previous month events and then call some rest api, and based on the result of this call, I want to disable some dates.
Calls of **this.nextClicked()** and **this.previousClicked();** are generated only after the rest api gave response.

I am using the **dateFilter** attribute, but all my variables are undefined

**TS**

```
  public filterDates(date: Date): boolean {
    if (this.apiResult !== undefined) {
      let d = this.pipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      return this.apiResult.has(d);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
 }
```

If you have any idea or any methods to change disabled dates programmatically
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To take the context into your `filterDates` method you need to use arrow functions instead of declaring it as a regular method as you did (otherwise the `this` keyword will be referring to the context inside `matDateFilter` class, where your `pipe` and `apiResult` don't exist) :

```js
filterDates = (date: Date): boolean => {
  if (this.apiResult !== undefined) {
    let d = this.pipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    return this.apiResult.has(d);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57989822?file=app/datepicker-filter-example.ts)