# Disabling future days using Angular mwl-calendar-month-view

Tags: angular, calendar

Is it possible to disable a day on Mat-Calendar?
Our project allows the employee to set a Time Entry on the actual and past days, but he or she cannot do it on future days...

Like this...
Today is 27th and tomorrow he can`t open the 28th day

**Edit: Sorry, I was checking the code, and isn't a mat-calendar... it´s a  mwl-calendar-month-view**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Mat Calendar Disable date based on Rest result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978516/angular-mat-calendar-disable-date-based-on-rest-result)

Comment: I'll test, but thanks

Comment: Please, also update the title of your question, it will be helpful for other users :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a function fo filter dates in your component. This function returns `true` to enable the date and `false` to disable it.

```
filterDates = (date: Date): boolean => {
  let today = new Date();
  return date < today;
}
```

And bind it to your `mat-calendar`:

```
<mat-calendar ... [dateFilter]="filterDates"></mat-calendar>
```

Comment: I, need to check because isn't a mat-calendar... it's a mwl-month-view, and I don't know if this interferes

Comment: I tried this yesterday, and was a good start point for me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible if you hook on to `beforeViewRender` and apply some CSS rules

Template:

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view (beforeViewRender)="applyDateSelectionPolicy($event)">
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

TS:

```
  dateIsValid(date: Date): boolean {
    return date.getTime() < new Date().getTime();
  }

  applyDateSelectionPolicy({ body }: { body: CalendarMonthViewDay[] }): void {
    body.forEach(day => {
      if (!this.dateIsValid(day.date)) {
        day.cssClass = 'disabled-date';
      }
    });
  }
```

CSS:

```
.disabled-date{
 opacity: .5;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar but your code has the same problem that mine.
We block the future days, like 29th... but 1st March isn't blocked, just 27th March... I'm thinking how can I cover this part

Comment: Do a console.log in the dateIsValid method to see if the problem is there, maybe the comparison is not working as it should be

Comment: and if i want to disable some hours in week view?